# HTML + CSS - Sending Image to Back

Tags: html, css, image

I recently ran across and issue concerning my background and text - as the background is displayed, and then the text is displayed below it. I have tried using multiple tutorials, but none seem to have worked.

Help would be appreciated!

Code is here: http://pastie.org/4331611

The current issue is shown clearly here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jDey.png

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: You really shouldn't use inline styles. Create a separate, external CSS file.

Comment: I have updated the post again, this time with an image to show the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do it:

```
<body>
   <div style="margin: 0px auto; width: 1000px; text-align: center;">
       <div style="background-image: url('http://files.enjin.com/71917/images/Status/BG.png');">Test Data</div>
```

But there are all kinds of problems with this code.  You shouldn't be using a center tag (I've demonstrated what you should do in the first DIV).  Also move the font details into the style attribute as well and along with the you should pull the styles out of the style attribute and put them in either a style tag in the HEAD or in an external stylesheet.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*styles go here*/
    </style>
</head>
```

ADDITION:

The picture helps me to better understand what you're trying to accomplish. I think what you really want to do is change up the nesting of your DIVs a bit. Try something like:

```
<div id="container" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 350px; text-align: center; background-image: url('http://...image.png');">
   <div id="theContentDivs">LOSTCRAFT SMP</div>
   <div id="theContentDivs">LOSTCRAFT PVP</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not fixed, thanks Michael, bit it did not work. My code has got head tags, but the code you provided did not work :(

Comment: The picture helps me to better understand what you're trying to accomplish.  I think what you really want to do is change up the nesting of your DIVs a bit.

Try something like:
    <div id="container" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 350px; text-align: center; background-image: url('http://...image.png');">
      <div id="theContentDivs">LOSTCRAFT SMP</div>
      <div id="theContentDivs">LOSTCRAFT PVP</div>
    </div>

Comment: Sorry I just appended that to my earlier answer as that wasn't readable at all :)